# Revise or delete my question?

Tags: discussion

My question:

[Concatenating a List of of sites and count of occurrences into a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26852808/concatenating-a-list-of-of-sites-and-count-of-occurrences-into-a-column/26853288?noredirect=1#comment42343106_26853288)

... became very complex and I honestly don't see it getting answered in its current state.  I am in the process of distilling the problem down to a concise example, but I don't know if I should delete the question entirely and start afresh (considering all the commenting that isn't germane to the core topic), or if I should just do a drastic revision.  Hogan put some time into giving me some insight and I appreciate it, so I am averse to simply deleting the post altogether.

In this case, what is good form?

Comment: Given the upvoted answer; I'm pretty sure you *can't* delete it. As long as you aren't changing the question; an edit would be appropriate anyways.

Comment: Another option might be to ask a new question if the question itself changed, referring to this and describing your different problem.

Comment: It's definitely the same problem, I just want to make it cleaner.  I get confused when I'm reading it, which is not a good sign.

Comment: Then definitely edit! We like cleaner questions :) If the comments are obsolete, flag for moderator cleanup

Comment: OK, will do, thanks for the advice.